# ALSA – Choppy audio with USB audio device after upgrading to Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, alsa

On Debian Wheezy, mplayer (and other audio players) would play audio without any choppiness.

After upgrading to Jessie, while playing audio through my USB sound card (SoundBlaster Live), I get a "skip" every 30 seconds or so (kind of like the skipping you would get with CD players back in the day if you jumped on the floor).

Anyone have any idea what the issue may be? Or how I can at least begin troubleshooting? I'm not sure what settings I can try fiddling with.

Comment: Have you tried a different sound card? Just to eliminate some possibilities.

Comment: No, it's the only one I have. It also worked fine _just_ before the update to Jessie, so it's likely not the sound card.

Comment: Suggestion: try a clean install of jessie alongside your current system. Assuming you have the space - if not, could you install on an external USB drive?

Comment: What do you mean "alongside"? I assume you mean on a different disk? This is not a bad suggestion, but in the end I need it to work on my current installation, because I have too much other things invested there. Let's say it works on the new installation. How do I know how to fix the original one? What configuration files do I compare, etc.?

Comment: Yes, I meant on a different disk. If it works on a fresh Jessie installation, you'll know something is wrong with your version. It will at least help to eliminate other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your player [without PulseAudio](https://wiki.debian.org/PulseAudio#Temporarily_suspend_and_run_an_application_without_PulseAudio):

```
$ pasuspender -- mplayer movie.mpg
```

If this helps, you've got a PulseAudio issue.  You can also find tuning tips on the page linked above.

Comment: I don't believe I have PulseAudio installed. `which pasuspender` gives me nothing.

Comment: So does mplayer still use its ALSA driver? Start it in a terminal, quit after a couple of seconds of playback and look for the line starting with `AO:`. What does it say?